# How can I remove the horizontal scrollbar in the bottom of a page?

Tags: html, wordpress

How can I remove the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of [this page](http://clikstick.com/)?

Comment: i figured out why there is a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom  its becuase of the width of the image of slider.

Comment: Improved flow of text and grammar; Describe the link in the anchor text rather than next to it.

Comment: Questions asking for help debugging are expected to contain, in the body of the question, the *relevant* portion of the source code, exactly what you wanted to achieve, and exactly what you got instead (for example, I see no scroll bar, so I can't see your problem). General questions about general problems are expected to include details about  the circumstances under which you see the problem, the general context, etc.

Comment: `html {overflow-x: hidden}`

Answer (score 0):

CSS rule:

html { overflow-x: hidden; }

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, I'm experiencing this issue only in certain resolutions.  If you can use a CSS3 rule, update your `.f-iphone` class like this:

```
.f-iphone {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 606px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  max-width: 1030px;
  background: url(../images/f-iphone.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Here's the browser support for CSS calc(): http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Note that if you do not do this, some text will be hidden in the "WHY CLIKSTICK" section.